# Laravel can not displayed image from public folder on the server

Tags: php, laravel, image, public-folders

I'm trying to display images from the storage/app/public folder and work on localhost and internal network, but not working when using the outside assess the page.

```
<a href="{{URL::asset('/storage/acknowledgement/'.$DNStatus->filename)}}" target="_blank" >
   <img  class="img-responsive pad" src="{{URL::asset('/storage/acknowledgement/'.$DNStatus->filename)}}">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're moving your code between localhost and your server via git, /public/storage is listed in the Laravel .gitignore by default

You'll need to copy the files to your server manually.

I wouldn't suggest storing your assets in /public/storage anyway, they should be in /public/assets or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the storage:link Artisan command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Comment: yes,i had used storage:link but not working on outside network

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this

```
<img  class="img-responsive pad" src="{{url('')}}/path_to_your_image_folder/{{$DNStatus->filename}}">
```